# How do I create a function to scramble the words of a sentence?

Tags: python, jython

I am trying to write a function that can take a sentence as an input and output the same list of words in a scrambled order.  So far I have the following:

```
import random
def scramble(sentence):
  split = sentence.split()
  shuffle(split)
  return ' '.join(split)
print scramble(sentence)
```

The issue is that Jython is returning an error vice the output I'm looking for.  I've been tweaking with the code for hours with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you format you code first  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
random.shuffle(split)
```

When you import from a module, that module's name becomes a *namespace*. In order to use any of its functions, you need to direct the Python interpreter that those functions reside in a certain namespace. Larger programs can have dozens (or more!) of import statements, and namespaces help keep everything clear, so you're not polluting the main (global) namespaces with potentially multiple functions with the same name.

When you do `from module import function` the name `function` is now in the global namespace, and you can use it without prefixing its originating module name on the front. This isn't always a great idea in larger programs, as you can lose track of things, but here if you wanted to change

```
import random
```

to

```
from random import shuffle
```

then your program would work as-is.

One other potential issue with your program - at least in the code you've shown, you haven't assigned a value to the variable `sentence`, so when you call `print scramble(sentence)` you'll get an error because `scramble()` has no input.

As a bit of advice, I wouldn't name a variable after a built-in function, as that can screw things up down the line. Maybe call it `shuffled` or something...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is on this line:

```
shuffle(split)
```

It is part of the `random` module, thus you need to change the line to this:

```
random.shuffle(split)
```

Alternatively, you can adjust your import line to be this:

```
from random import shuffle
```

Then you don't need to adjust the `shuffle(split)` line